# Using argparse with argument values that begin with a dash ("-")

Tags: python, argparse

#### What I want to do

I want to migrate a script from `docopt` to `argparse`. My script takes a positional argument for input file(s), then calls another command-line tool. It also takes an optional argument option that allows the user to specify additional arguments and options that will be passed to that command-line tool.

So, I allow the user to call:

```
my_program.py INPUT --extra-options "-foo bar -baz"
```

These `--extra-options` are then added to the other program I'm calling from inside my script, e.g.:

```
other_program -foo bar -baz INPUT
```

#### Problem

Now, having migrated the argument parsing to `argparse`, this does not work anymore:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("input", nargs="+")
parser.add_argument("-e", "--extra-options", type=str)
parser.add_argument("-f", "--force", default=False, action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

When I call the same command, it says:

```
error: argument -e/--extra-options: expected one argument
```

But `-e` was given one argument (`-foo bar -baz`, to be precise)! My expectation was that the shell would group the argument based on the double-quotes, and `argparse` would understand that.

Now, in the manual, we find:

> positional arguments may only begin with - if they look like negative numbers and there are no options in the parser that look like negative numbers … If you have positional arguments that must begin with - and don’t look like negative numbers, you can insert the pseudo-argument '--' which tells parse_args() that everything after that is a positional argument

But this does not apply here – I want `-e` to just parse the next word from the shell as its argument. The problem in this case is the other option `-f/--force` – as soon as I remove it, or give it some other name (e.g., `-x`), the arguments are parsed correctly. Apparently the `f` from `-foo` clashes with the `-f/--force` option.

#### What I've tried

I looked into the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174992/cant-get-argparse-to-read-quoted-string-with-dashes-in-it), but none of them solves the issue.

- I can't force users to specify this option differently (e.g., starting with a space, using `=`, ending with a space, …), as it would break backwards compatibility with existing scripts.
- I don't want to use a deprecated module (`optparse`).
- The `parse_known_args` solution does not work in this case.
- The `nargs=argparse.PARSER` solution does not work either.
- Removing `nargs` did not help either.

How can I get `argparse` to deal with argument values starting with `-` in this case?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks – I had a look and updated my question. Unfortunately, none of the answers there really helps in this case. I know it may just be a bug or lack of feature in `argparse`. (I'd accept "It's currently impossible" as an answer.)

Comment: That's what the other answers tell you; it is a bug in argparse. The workaround is to use `-e="...."` or `--extra-options="..."` (note the `=` sign).

Comment: This is still a duplicate; that there is no satisfying answer for you on the other post is regrettable, but not something a re-hash of the same terrain is going to resolve. You could try adding a bounty to the other post to see if anyone has got any better solutions.

Comment: Sure, I understand. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's wrong with `argparse.PARSER` (or `argparse.REMAINDER')?

Comment: In a sense this goes beyond the earlier SO and the 9334 bug/issue.  As long as `"-f..."` or `"--foo"` match a defined flag, `argparse` will interpret it as a flag, not an argument for the previous flag.  Quotes don't matter, except to keep the shell from splitting words.  That behavior is built into the parsing algorithm.

Comment: @hpaulj I couldn't get it to work with `argparse.PARSER` … could you maybe give me a concrete example? It's unfortunate that argparse is trying to be too clever here.

Comment: I don't think I have a enough rep in this area to reopen it alone; so won't try to write an answer.  But I think the only complicating thing is that it returns a list value, not just a string.

Comment: @hpaulj Could you just post the respective line of code in a comment? I tried setting that option for the affected argument but it didn't work.

Comment: I added to my answer in the `duplicate`.