# argparse - valid argument value falsely ignored

Tags: python, argparse, argv

Consider following MCVE:

```
import sys
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-t", "--test")
parser.add_argument("-o", "--other")
assert sys.argv == ['mcve.py', '-o', '-t 123']
parsed = parser.parse_args()
assert parsed.other == "-t 123"
```

And its' invocation:

```
lrogalsk-mac01:src lrogalsk$ python mcve.py -o "-t 123"
usage: mcve.py [-h] [-t TEST] [-o OTHER]
mcve.py: error: argument -o/--other: expected one argument
```

As you can see, values in shell are interpreted correctly and passed to Python process as *separate* command line arguments. Nevertheless, `argparse` parsing mechanism still rejects this value (likely because it begins with match of another parameter, `-t`).

Changing invocation to space-prepended value (see below) and adjusting assertions in MCVE script makes it work, but this for me is merely workaround and not an actual solution.

```
lrogalsk-mac01:src lrogalsk$ python mcve.py -o " -t 123"
```

Is there any known way of fixing this behaviour in argparse?

Set-up details:

```
lrogalsk-mac01:src lrogalsk$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
```

Comment: Assertion is correct. Argument is wrapped in quotation marks in shell invocation for a reason.

Comment: what if you do `mcve.py -o "'-t 123'"`?

Comment: `sys.argv` is `['mcve.py', '-o', "'-t 123'"]`, parsing succeeded, but only because value string does not start with `-t`, as now it starts with `'-t`. I don't see how wrapping value in quotation marks differs from prepending value with space in this context.

Comment: More on this at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174992/cant-get-argparse-to-read-quoted-string-with-dashes-in-it.  I list several work arounds.  Or stick with `optparse`.

Answer (score 1):

In the 'argparse' documentation, this case is mentioned (16.4.4.3):

> The parse_args() method attempts to give errors whenever the user has
>   clearly made a mistake, but some situations are inherently ambiguous.
>   For example, the command-line argument -1 could either be an attempt
>   to specify an option or an attempt to provide a positional argument.
>   The parse_args() method is cautious here: positional arguments may
>   only begin with - if they look like negative numbers and there are no
>   options in the parser that look like negative numbers

For positional arguments, you can prepend a '--', but in your case that doesn't seem to work. Instead, the use of `subparsers` is supported, so

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help = 'the subparsers')
parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('o', help = 'the o option')
parser_a.add_argument('-t', '--test')
parsed = parser.parse_args()
print(parsed.test)
```

works. Calling the script with

```
python mcve.py o -t 123
```

gives the output

```
123
```