# Python parser will not accept '-' as an argument

Tags: python, argparse

My python script is being sent "-E" as an argument string but I am getting the following error

```
error: argument -emIdentify: expected one argument
```

When I send it ".E" or "_E" everything is fine, how can I get it to accept "-E"

My code is

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='')
parser.add_argument("-emIdentify")
logging.debug( 'processing emIdentify: ' + args.emIdentify + "<br/>" )
```

Comment: In `python script.py -emIdentify -E`, the '-E' is seen as a flag string (like '-emidentify'.  Use the `=` form as suggested in the answer to get around that limitation.  As a matter of form I'd also define your argument with `--emIdentify` (double -- for longer names).

Comment: This is a known issue; the `=` solution was provided in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16175115/901925

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
python filename.py -emIdentify=-E
```

Comment: I'm getting it from an html form input where the user inputs the string they wish to use and it is passed as a parameter. When the user inputs .E or _E all works fine but I get the error for -E. I think it may be the line parser.add_argument("-emIdentify") is being read as parser.add_argument("--E").