# Python argparse: Leading dash in argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, command-line-arguments, argparse

I'm using Python's [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module to parse command line arguments. Consider the following simplified example,

```
# File test.py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-s', action='store')
parser.add_argument('-a', action='append')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

which can successfully be called like

```
python test.py -s foo -a bar -a baz
```

A single argument is required after `-s` and after each `-a`, which may contain spaces if we use quotation. If however an argument starts with a dash (`-`) and does not contain any spaces, the code crashes:

```
python test.py -s -begins-with-dash -a bar -a baz
```

> error: argument -s: expected one argument

I get that it interprets `-begins-with-dash` as the beginning of a new option, which is illegal as `-s` has not yet received its required argument. It's also pretty clear though that no option with the name `-begins-with-dash` has been defined, and so it should not interpret it as an option in the first place. How can I make `argparse` accept arguments with one or more leading dashes?

Comment: Due to the `argparse` parsing approach it is hard, if not impossible, to do this. https://bugs.python.org/issue9334

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174992/cant-get-argparse-to-read-quoted-string-with-dashes-in-it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't get argparse to read quoted string with dashes in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174992/cant-get-argparse-to-read-quoted-string-with-dashes-in-it)

Answer (score 26):

You can force argparse to interpret an argument as a value by including an equals sign:

```
python test.py -s=-begins-with-dash -a bar -a baz
Namespace(a=['bar', 'baz'], s='-begins-with-dash')
```

Comment: True, though what I really want is a solution from within the Python script, allowing it to be called like `-s -begins-with-dash`.

Comment: The equal sign is also limited to single value arguments (i.e. can't do this with nargs arguments).

Answer (score 4):

If you are instead trying to provide multiple values to one argument:

```
parser.add_argument('-a', action='append', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)
```

will grab *everything* after `-a` on the command line and shove it in `a`.

```
python test.py -toe -a bar fi -fo -fum -s fee -foo
usage: test.py [-h] [-s S] [-a ...]
test.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -toe

python test.py -a bar fi -fo -fum -s fee -foo
Namespace(a=[['bar', 'fi', '-fo', '-fum', '-s', 'fee', '-foo']], s=None)
```

Note that even though `-s` is a recognized argument, `argparse.REMAINDER` adds it to the list of args found by `-a` since it is after `-a` on the command line

Comment: Provided you have the flexibility of choosing which param goes where. This method also doesn't allow you to have two of these types of arguments in one command line.