# Argparse argument value prefix with --

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

I find myself in the (unenviable) position of needing to pass a collection of arguments as a single (comma separated) argument to a script, like so:

```sh
python example.py --extra_args '--argument1,value1,--argument2,--value2'
```

It seems that `argparse` doesn't like values with leading '--'.

### Minimal Working Example

For example, define `example.py` as follows

```py
# example.py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--extra_args', type=str, default=None)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.extra_args)
```

and run the command above and you get the error:

```sh
python example.py --extra_args '--argument1,value1,--argument2,--value2'
# usage: example.py [-h] [--extra_args EXTRA_ARGS]
# example.py: error: argument --extra_args: expected one argument
```

Looking to improve on my current workaround, which is to use a different prefix other than `'--'`.

### Answered

This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174992/cant-get-argparse-to-read-quoted-string-with-dashes-in-it) contained the answer I was looking for:

```sh
python example.py --extra_args=--argument1,value1,--argument2,--value2
```

works!

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174992/cant-get-argparse-to-read-quoted-string-with-dashes-in-it)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't get argparse to read quoted string with dashes in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174992/cant-get-argparse-to-read-quoted-string-with-dashes-in-it) Note that there are multiple different approaches